# Updating a sub-form based on a list box selection - Access 2013

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Afternoon all.

**A bit of context:**

Our office recently moved from Access 2010 to 2013, originally I had assumed all was well and everything worked as it did in 2010.

However recent revelations have proved otherwise.

In 2010 I had a form with a list box on it (linked to a query), users could select a record from the list (the list box would only show certain fields), and the entire record would be displayed in a sub-form underneath the list. This was achieved via the method found here: [Updating a sub-form based on a list box selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977779/updating-a-sub-form-based-on-a-list-box-selection)
which worked perfectly.

**The issue:**

Upon "upgrading" to access 2013 this no longer works correctly, the sub-form will display the field names as expected, however the selected record will not populate the sub-form. It's set up the exact same way as it was in 2010 (I've also just tested this on Access 2010 on an un-networked machine and it works as it used to).

Is there a new method required that I am unaware of in Access 2013? I've tried looking about and had no joy, everything I find is related to 2010 or before.

Thank you for you time,

Ben.

Comment: I have just tested with 2013, and the same idea works. Have you tried all the corruption steps, that is, back-up, compact & repair, decompile, and if you still have problems, import to a fresh database front end?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Remou, turns out its due to Remote Desktop not refreshing the sub-form upon list click. 
(I do apologize for not mentioning it was over RD before, I had assumed it would not be related!)
If I scroll the sub-form left or right then the record magically appears... time to research this now.
Thanks again.